# use Ajax id #insert then form not validate

Tags: jquery, ajax

here iam write a ajax jquery code

```
        **ajax jquery code:**
           <script type="text/javascript">

          $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#insert").click(function(){

          var OPRID=$("#OPRID").val();
          var OPRDEFNDESC=$("#OPRDEFNDESC").val();
        $.post('opr_insert.php', {OPRID: OPRID, OPRDEFNDESC: OPRDEFNDESC},
             function(data){
         $("#message").html(data);
         $("#message").hide();
        $("#message").fadeIn(1500); //Fade in the data given by the insert.php file
              });
        return false;
           });
         });
         </script>
```

here my html and Ajax code both are below my problem is that when i am use Ajax id #insert then form not validate by input input type="text" required how can possible both i have using ajax insert and validation thanks in advance here my HTML code

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="OPRID"  id="OPRID"  
   minlength="5"  required/>
<input type="text" class="form-control required" name="OPRDEFNDESC"  id="OPRDEFNDESC" 
  required>


  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   <a id="insert"> <button  type="Submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> 
      Save changes</button>
            </a>
```

Comment: It depends on which validation library that you used. You could use JQuery validation for example. So in this case, which library that you use?

Comment: i think i am not use any type of JQuery validation only use required field validation

Comment: can you plz help how can validation use using in my ajax code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this and let me know if it is working. Thanks. See the ** codes. Hope it helps.

`$('#divAjaxLoaderGif')` is the div that contains your Ajax-Loader.gif

**ajax jquery code:**

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#insert").click(function(){

      var OPRID=$("#OPRID").val();
      var OPRDEFNDESC=$("#OPRDEFNDESC").val();

     $('#divAjaxLoaderGif').show();  // show the loading message.
**$.ajax({
    url: "opr_insert.php",
    type: "POST",
    data:  {OPRID: OPRID, OPRDEFNDESC: OPRDEFNDESC},
    success : function(data){
         $("#message").html(data);
     $("#message").hide();
    $("#message").fadeIn(1500); //Fade in the data given by the insert.php file
        $('#divAjaxLoaderGif').hide(); // hide the loading message
    }
});**

    return false;
       });
     });
     </script>
```

Comment: can you plz tell me how use to show a "success & failed" message